# AngularJS change bound-data value after time delay

Tags: angularjs

I want to change a bound-data value by controller after some time delay, but not working, the following is a very simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('controller',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.color='red';
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.color='blue';
    }, 0);
}])
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="controller">
{{color}} <input ng-model="color">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `setTimeout(function(){})`. Use `$timeout` instead (Angular way)

```
app.controller('controller',['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.color='red';
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.color='blue';
    });
}])
```

Also for `0` milliseconds you can omit delay value

---

On start `$scope.color` has value `'red'` . `setTimeout` does not trigger digest cycle so when you change `color` to `blue`  it will take no effect.

The `$timeout` **triggers** digest cycle and therefore in HTML `{{color}}` we will see `blue`

Comment: great, I just read some tutorials on digest cycle, now I understand. thanks.

Comment: @FanheKong you welcome to accept if it helped u, tnx

Answer (score 1):

```
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.color='blue';
  }, 10000);
```

OR

```
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.color='blue';
  }, 20000);
```

use second parameter as millisecond. you can put any value you want. if you want 1 second after use 10000 and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't know digest cycle concepts until this question.